# Window.ga is undefined in Firefox when using Google Tag Manager in React

Tags: reactjs, firefox, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a standard React project and am using Google Tag Manager to load analytics on the page. I have the Google Tag Manager in the head of the index.html. I have some code to retrieve the clientId from the window.ga object and then populate it into a field in my state on one of my components called "gaClientId". I have a method that retrieves the clientId and gets called in componentDidMount(). This works as expected in Chrome and IE but not Firefox for some odd reason. Not exactly sure what the issue is. I have checked to make sure that firefox is not blocking the tracker and have noticed in the console that if I console.log(window.ga) I get the undefined message before Google Tag Manager loads. Didn't know if that is where the issue is. Here is my method:

```
getGAClientId() {
try {
  const tracker = ga.getAll()[0];
  let clientId = tracker.get("clientId");
  this.setState({ gaClientId: clientId });
} catch (e) {
  return null;
}
```

}

and here is my state in the component:

```
this.state = {
    firstname: '',
    lastname: '',
    email: '',
    gaClientId: ''  
};
```

This is being set to the value of a hidden form field like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="this.state.gaClientId" name="gaClientId" />
```

Here is the head of my index.html just to show you:

```
<head>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>
  (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
    w[l] = w[l] || [];
    w[l].push({
      "gtm.start": new Date().getTime(),
      event: "gtm.js"
    });
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j = d.createElement(s),
      dl = l != "dataLayer" ? "&l=" + l : "";
    j.async = true;
    j.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=" + i + dl;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
  })(window, document, "script", "dataLayer", "GTM-xxxxxxx");
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
</head>
```

Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Figured it out! I needed to add a setTimeout() to my getGaClientId() call in my componentDidMount. I just updated the code to the below to fix it.

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.getGAClientId();
  }, 2000);
}
```

I guess the load order of when Google Analytics was loading to when my method was being called was off.